# How to find position of big value in python list array

Tags: python

`list = [3,5,1,8,9]`
I want to find positions of the maximum value in the list

Comment: lst.index(max(lst)) Try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, but it will give you the index of the first occurrence:

```
>>> l = [3,5,1,8,9]
>>> l.index(max(l))
4
```

I strongly suggest you not use the name of built-in functions as `list` for variables.